# angular-loading-bar does not change loading bar color even after the css class is overrided

Tags: css, angular

To enable [angular-loading-bar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar) with different color , I have overwritten the css classes:

```
#loading-bar .bar {
    background: #33ba3a;
    height: 4px;
}

#loading-bar-spinner .spinner-icon {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border: solid 4px transparent;
    border-top-color: #6959A0;
    border-left-color: #6959A0;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

But somehow, it does not change the bydefault color of angular-loading-bar. So what is the solution to change the color?

Comment: Did you tried by applying !important?

Comment: @SagarKodte it worked. Can you tell me how to change the color from loading-bar.css file , so that it does not have to override anything?

Comment: Just open loading-bar.css and find there you will get the css applied for that particular class or id. You can change there.